# Java/ Sort array which contain points

Tags: java, arrays

I have array with points: `Point[] p = new Point[]`

I want to sort it by x, and then by y.
Meaning, If I have

```
Point A = (1, 2)
Point B = (2, 1)
Point C = (1, 3)
Point D = (2, 2)
```

After sorting, I will get: `[(1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2)]`

I try to use `Arrays.sort()`, but point isn't comparable. There is an easy way to do that?

Comment: Hint: Use `Comparator` or `Comparable` interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) with a custom [`Comparer<Point>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
Arrays.sort(p, new Comparator<Point>() {
    int compare(Point a, Point b) {
        int xComp = Integer.compare(a.x, b.x);
        if(xComp == 0)
            return Integer.compare(a.y, b.y);
        else
            return xComp;
    }
});
```

Sidenotes:

- If some of your `Point` objects may be `null`, you must handle this
  in `compareTo`.
- If your `Point` is not an AWT point but your own
  class, you'd better let it implement `Comparable`.

Comment: Where I need to put this statement?

Comment: @TomAvni Wherever you tried `Arrays.sort` before. It's just an overload for arrays of non-`Comparable` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Let `Point` implement the `Comparable` interface, and override its `compareTo` method to suit your needs.

```
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Point p) {
      if (this.x != p.x) {
        return Integer.compareTo(this.x, p.x);
      } else {
        return Integer.compareTo(this.y, p.y);
      }
    }
```

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-sort-arraylist-in-java-example.html#ixzz2S2i9k5V3

This requires editing the `Point` class. If that's not possible, see other answers for alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

you can try (pseudo code).

```
   Arrays.sort(p, new Comparator<Point >() {
        public int compare(Point p1, Point p2) {

             //here operations and return
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Point does not implement comparable you can create your own class for comparison:

```
public class Sorter implements Comparator 
{
  public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
  {
    Point pointOne = (Point)o1;
    Point pointTwo = (Point)o2;
    return ((pointOne.getX()+pointOne.getY())+"").compareTo(((pointTwo.getX()+pointTwo.getY())+""));
  }
}
```

Then yo can use this Sorter class:

```
void mySortingFunc(Point[] points)
{
  Arrays.sort(points, new Sorter());
}
```